# How to set local file path for web service?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I am developing as rest WS in whcih i want to set the system property.

```
String AUTH_CONF = "http://localhost:8080/RestWS/WebContent/WEB-INF/authwl.conf";
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", AUTH_CONF);
```

when i am going to run the project it is givving error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Configuration Error:
No such file or directory
at com.sun.security.auth.login.ConfigFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I also have put the authwl.conf file in respwctive folder.For this project i am using tomcat7.0.

If anybody have solution please post it.

Comment: you need to put the relative path of the local file, not the http url, what's the file path locally?

Comment: D://Project//RestWS//WebContent//WEB-INF//authwl.conf